# Rails - Nested Form add works, but records are not deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm using nested forms in my rails app and I have a simple parent-child setup:

Models:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exptypes, :dependent => :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :exptypes, :allow_destroy => true

class Exptype < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :experiment
```

Views:

Parent:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@experiment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :exptypes do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'exptype_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add an Experimental Type", :exptypes %></p>
```

Child:

```
<h2>Experiment type</h2>
<p> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this Experiment" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type_name %>
  </div>
</p>
```

The addition of many children works fine, but when I try to remove any from the list (by clicking the button created by `link_to_remove`), the nested form disappears, but when I hit update, the show form still shows the "deleted" child.

Comment: How would you remove any of the child record through `edit`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant in my view. I hit the button created by `<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this Experiment" %>` and it removes that portion of the form.

Comment: Try giving this line `<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this Experiment" %> `at the end inside the another div you have.

Comment: No change, the button itself seems to work - it removes the nested form - but the association itself still isn't destroyed! Moving the line around the partial did nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Found the error, I didn't have `:_destroy` in my permitted parameters in my controller.

Hope this helps someone else!

Edit:

My controller's strong params method looks as follows:

```
def experiment_params
  params.require(:experiment).permit(:_destroy, :experiment_number, :date, :title, :pi, 
    :biocontrol_run_num, :goals, :description, :str, :exp_type)
end
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: If you had tagged `Rails 4` ,my first question is supposed to be about `strong params`. Any ways you got it!

Comment: @Pavan I agree, with the freedom the Rails framework provides, Strong Params are almost counter-intuitive

Comment: @Pavan, I shall remember to tag it as such next time I have a question!

Comment: Sir, how will I add the `:_destroy` in my controller. Thanks

Comment: Added an edit to the answer, should help. The `params` method will be at the bottom of the controller, just add `:_destroy` to the `permit` arguments.